# azure cli command works in powershell but not bash

Tags: bash, powershell, azure-cli

I have a command on the form

```bash
az network bastion ssh --name hyphen-text --resource-group another-hypen-text --target-resource-id /subscriptions/1c715f48-0ae9-121a-44f2-72683c152f33/resourceGroups/text-with-hyphen/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/more-text-with-hyphen --auth-type AAD
```

All name values are written in kebab-case, and subscription id uses hexadecimal characters (0-9,a-f). The whole command shoud be valid ascii.

The same command, but with linebreaks and name values replaced with <*>:

```bash
az network bastion ssh \
  --name <somename> \
  --resource-group <some_rg> \
  --target-resource-id /subscriptions/<sub_id>/resourceGroups/<some_rg>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<some_vm> \
  --auth-type AAD
```

to connect to an azure vm via bastion using ssh, where <*> is replaced by appropriate values.

NOTE: the line breaks `\` were added for readability, and because it shouldn't affect bash execution. It was tested without linebreaks both for bash and powershell.

The command worked completely fine in powershell, while in bash (git bash in vscode), I get the following error message:

> Please enter a valid resource ID. If this is not working, try opening the JSON view of your resource (in the Overview tab), and copying the full resource ID.

I have tried putting the flag values inside double quotes without successs. Powershell and bash both use the same az CLI

```
bash version: GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
PSVersion: 5.1.19041.3930
azure-cli version:  2.56.0
```

Comment: Just to avoid confusion: the command cannot work as shown in PowerShell, because it doesn't support ``\`` for line continuation (requires `\``)

Comment: @mklement0 true, I added the `\ ` for increased readability only

Comment: The problem must be with the concrete argument you're passing to `--target-resource-id` - the abstract form you've posted doesn't reveal a problem. If you fear revealing sensitive information, replace it with dummy values; in order to be able to diagnose the problem, a  syntactically equivalent form of your actual argument must be shown.

Comment: @mklement0 I now replaced the <*> in the one-liner command with values following the same format as the actual command

Comment: I'm afraid that still doesn't explain your symptoms - none of these arguments are subject to interpretation by Bash (there are no metacharacters inside the arguments, such as spaces or `$`).

Comment: @mklement0 yes, I'm beginning to suspect that is related to how windows deals with ssh key permissions, though this is not confirmed ATM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this for git bash
MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 az network bastion ssh ...

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).